# Replace strings in a big text file based on fields from a CSV file

Tags: sed, csv, replace

I have a big text file (roughly 2GB). I have a csv file that has the following fields:

```
rowID,pattern,other
1,abc_1z1,90
2,abc_1z2,90
3,abc_1z10,80
4,abc_3p1,77
...
```

My interest is: replace the content of the big file as follows. Whenever a string in the big file matches a "pattern" in my CSV (second field), it will replace that string by the corresponding "rowID" (first field).

This is what I have tried using sed, which is extremely slow (also due to in-place replacement of the file). But, is there any faster solution?

```
while read f1 f2 f3; 
do 
    sed -i "s/$f2/$f1/g" bigfile; 
done < map.csv
```

Note that map.csv contains over 500000 rows.

Comment: please show some samples line of `map.csv` and expected output applied based on given given sample `big.txt` file

Answer (score 0):

*Note that sed replaces regular expressions not strings - I'm going to assume that is not an issue for your use case, since your current solution uses it.*

One way would be to pre-process `map.csv` into a sequence of expressions to pass to a single invocation of `sed -f`:

```
awk -F, 'NR>1 {printf "s/%s/%s/g\n", $2, $1}' map.csv | sed -f - bigfile
```

(add `-i` only once you are satisfied that it is doing the right thing).

Comment: Isn't it too expensive? The CSV itself has >500000 rows.  Sorry, I forgot to mention this in my question.

Comment: @Coder, this solution will process your big file once. Your while loop will process the big file N times (where N is the number of records in the map.csv). This is about as efficient as you can get.

Comment: @glennjackman the result of awk is a big string that goes into sed. This froze my computer for 5 hours. This is not feasible in my computer that is 4GB ram. Also, NR>=1.